# Runga Kutta - Why does my accuracy get worse with negative values of $\lambda$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am using the 4th order RK method to approximate solution for the IVP $x'(t) = \lambda x + \cos(t) - \lambda \sin(t)$, $x(0)=0$. The analytical solution for this IVP is $x(t) = \sin(t)$. On the interval $[0,5]$ with step size $h=0.01$

I am asked to use the 4th order RK method for $\lambda = 5,-5, -10$. I notice from my graph that the approximations with $\lambda = -5,-10$ are not good. Why is this?

```
clear;
clc;
%initial value point
x0 = 0;

%interval defined by exercise
a = 0;
b = 5;

exactSol = @(t)sin(t);

%All three equations for \lambda = 5, -5, and -10
f1 = @(x,t)5*x + cos(t) -5*sin(t);
f2 = @(y,t)-5*y + cos(t) +5*sin(t);
f3 = @(z,t)-10*z + cos(t) +10*sin(t);

%vector form for coding purpose
t(1) = [0];
x(1) = [x0];
y(1) = [x0];
z(1) = [x0];

h = 0.01;
n = round((b-a)/h);
for i=1:n
    t(i+1) = t(i) + h;
    k1x = f1(x(i),t(i));
    k2x = f1(t(i) + h/2,x(i) + h/2*k1x);
    k3x = f1(t(i) + h/2,x(i) + h/2*k2x);
    k4x = f1(t(i) + h/2,x(i) + h/2*k3x);

    j1x = f2(y(i),t(i));
    j2x = f2(t(i) + h/2,y(i) + h/2*j1x);
    j3x = f2(t(i) + h/2,y(i) + h/2*j2x);
    j4x = f2(t(i) + h/2,y(i) + h/2*j3x);

    p1x = f3(z(i),t(i));
    p2x = f3(t(i) + h/2,z(i) + h/2*p1x);
    p3x = f3(t(i) + h/2,z(i) + h/2*p2x);
    p4x = f3(t(i) + h/2,z(i) + h/2*p3x);

    x(i+1) = x(i) + h/6*(k1x+2*k2x+k2x*k3x+k4x);
    y(i+1) = y(i) + h/6*(j1x+2*j2x+j2x*j3x+j4x);
    z(i+1) = z(i) + h/6*(p1x+2*p2x+p2x*p3x+p4x);


end
% L for lambda
plot(t,x, 'DisplayName', 'L = 5')
hold on
plot(t,y, 'DisplayName', 'L = -5') 
hold on
plot(t,z, 'DisplayName', 'L = -10')
hold on
fplot(exactSol, [0,5], '--', 'DisplayName', 'Exact Solution')
ylim([0, 5])
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Solution')

legend('show')
```

All three approximations do not seem very good at all. Did I do something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `k2x*k3x` in the line defining `x(i+1)`, and correspondingly for `y` and `z`. I think it ought to be `2*k3x` instead. Also, `k4x` is supposed to be `f1(t(i) + h,x(i) + h*k3x)`, and correspondingly for `j` and `p`.

Comment: Ah, thank you spotting this. Along with what LutzL suggested and what you have noticed I have solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a quiet minute and compare

```
f1 = @(x,t)5*x + cos(t) -5*sin(t);

k1x = f1(x(i),t(i));

k2x = f1(t(i) + h/2,x(i) + h/2*k1x);
```

look at the order of arguments.

---

I'd also recommend making a function `RK4step(f,x,t,h)` to reduce the size of the main program.